# Excel compare and replace between two spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a task of taking information from say spreadsheet A, i.e., two columns name and number

```
 Smith,joe | 3446
```

and comparing and entering the number field into the matching person on a separate spreadsheet.

Can anyone tell me a simple way in which to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the name you want to search for and the name as it appears in the lookup table are identical, you'll want to use a VLOOKUP formula:

```
 =VLOOKUP([lookupname],[referencetable],[columnnumber],False)
```

As an example, if your name is in cell A2 and the reference table is on Sheet2 (with column A containing the name, column B containing the number, and the table spreading from row 1 to 900), your formula would look like this:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$900,2,False)
```

Note the dollar signs in the formula - these "lock" references, so you can copy the formula elsewhere without the reference moving about.

The "False" tells the formula to look only for exact matches.

Comment: You beat me to it! +1

Comment: Luck of the draw - I just happened to be passing through.